# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, syntax-error

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YLfc.png)

I tried to run a query with 2 IF keyword. I ma getting a syntex error in the second IF clause. How can I keep the second IF different from the first one.

Comment: I suspect you need a comma after `temperature`.

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: your query seems to be MySQL not SQL server. which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: You can't use BigQuery [`IF` operator syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#if) in SQL Server statements. And even in BigQuery you need to delimit columns with commas.

Comment: @RF1991: I don't think it's SQL Server *or* MySQL - that's the BigQuery UI...

Answer (score 0):

Next time please give your statement as text, not a screenshot.
You need a comma separating temperature and windspeed. After correcting that, next error will be in wdsp, do you want it as provided or cast to float64?